# Cyclopentadiene/etc. hydrophobicity after nitrogen atom substitution at a double bond?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond

If I take a compound like cyclopentadiene ($\ce{C5H6}$) and I substitute a nitrogen for a carbon at one of the $\ce{C=C}$ bonds (making a $\ce{C=N}$ bond), how does this typically change the hydrophobicity of the compound?

The problem is that I'm not really a chemist.  My thought here is that nitrogen is more electronegative than carbon, so this will polarize the bond, induce a dipole, and make the molecule more hydrophilic.  In general, it seems to me that mixing together atoms of differing electronegativity in alkane or alkene/etc. compounds should create dipoles that can interact with polar solvent molecules, improving hydrophilicity.

As an additional thought, how would the nitrogen substitution effect stacking interactions between the substituted ring and a regular molecule of cyclopentadiene?  My guess here would be that hydrophobic effects would cause a more favorable pi-stacking interaction between two unsubstituted copies of cyclopentadiene relative to cyclopentadiene and the aforementioned and described nitrogen substituted version of the molecule.

To clarify, by "stacking interactions" I mean the sort of $\ce{C=C}$ stacking interactions that lead to cycloaddition reactions, not that the two rings will lie on top of one-another (as in the case of something like a pair of benzene molecules).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cyclic unsaturated imine (Schiff base) will be more hydrophilic for the nitrogen lone pair hydrogen bonding and being a Lewis base toward water.  You do know that CpH [4 + 2} Diels-Alder reaction reversibly thermally dimerizes, right?  The endo-dimer is an exo-flip then hydrogenation away from JP-10 cruise missile fuel.

The cyclic imine, ${2H}$-pyrrole is an isomer of pyrrole.  One expects it will be labile toward proton migration in base.

http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.7330.html 
http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.5256848.html 
Click the Properties tab, etc.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the jet fuel composition. :)  Do you know if the lone pair will effect stacking?

Comment: Neither the imine nor CpH is aromatic for the ring methylene.  There will be adverse steric interactions if two such molecules approach.

Comment: I thought one could perhaps have offset stacking interactions between the two CpH rings?  Where just a pair of double bonds stack on one-another?

Comment: As you say, there is a CpH / CpH cycloaddition reaction, so I thought this requires this sort of edge-wise stacking interaction?

Comment: @user5420 In the transition state of the Diels-Alder reaction, the 2 CpH molecules are stacked with their double bonds perpendicular to each other, as it is, for example,  shown in the image on http://orgo.curvedarrow.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=144.

Comment: @JannisAndreska Thank you for the graphic!  What about a 2+2 cycloaddition reaction?  Would we have a parallel stacking interaction?  Or am I off the mark with this suggestion?

Comment: For a 2+2 cycloaddition, parallel stacking should be favorable.

Comment: @JannisAndreska So, do you think C = C / C = C parallel stacking, as opposed to C = C / C = N parallel stacking, would be more energetically favorable?  This guess is based on the (here unprotonated) nitrogen having a lone pair and being more hydrophilic (as per Uncle Al's answer)?

Comment: In the transition state of a cycloaddition, parallel stacking of both can be possible. The stacking (perpendicular or parallel) also depends on the symmetry of the molecular orbitals which take part in the reaction.

Comment: @JannisAndreska But in the case of the C = N - R / C = C stack, there would perhaps be a penalty from displacing a water molecule if we're in aqueous solvent?

Comment: Yes, I think the compound with the C=N bond will be better hydrated and more soluble in water than the compound with C=C bond. Cyclopentadiene is actually poorly soluble in water (1.8 mg/L according to http://www.guidechem.com/reference/dic-4966.html).

Comment: @JannisAndreska Unfortunately, I don't have any experience to be able to determine whether this means that the cycloaddition reaction rate will be one- or three-/etc. orders of magnitude slower in aqueous solvent due to the increased hydrophilicity of the C = N bond relative to the C = C bond.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the reaction will proceed more slowly, if at all. For such a reaction, I would recommend using an organic solvent in which both reactants are readily soluble.